# Element of Dataframe column and its type relations to original array element

Tags: python, pandas

In the code below I start with a numpy string-array (typecode:'U') and then create a pandas df from it. Afterwards I look at the type of an individual element and it is just an ordinary ptyhon str - hence it seems to "forget" the numpy-datatype (which should be <class 'numpy.str_'>).
However, if I do the same with a numpy int-array it remembers the dtype and spits out: <class 'numpy.int64'>. (I also have an ordinary python list as a comparison)

```
a = np.array(["Hi"])
type(a[0])
#<class 'numpy.str_'>
b = ["Hi"]
type(b[0])
#<class 'str'>
df_a = pd.DataFrame({"val": a})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({"val": b})
type(df_a["val"][0]) # <class 'str'>
type(df_b["val"][0]) # <class 'str'>
# NOTE: Same type although originally created with different types

###compare with numbers:
a = np.array([1])
type(a[0]) # <class 'numpy.int64'>
b = [1]
type(b[0]) # <class 'int'>
df_a = pd.DataFrame({"val": a})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({"val": b})
type(df_a["val"][0]) # <class 'numpy.int64'>
type(df_b["val"][0]) # <class 'numpy.int64'>


###compare with numbers - but without default size:
a = np.array([1],dtype='i2')
type(a[0]) # <class 'numpy.int16'>
b = [1]
type(b[0]) # <class 'int'>
df_a = pd.DataFrame({"val": a})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({"val": b})
type(df_a["val"][0]) # <class 'numpy.int16'>
type(df_b["val"][0]) # <class 'numpy.int64'>
```

So my general question: If I create a numpy array whose individual element have type "x" under which circumstances is an element in the created pd.DataFrame of the same type?
And why does the string-type convert in the manner displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas columns are numpy arrays under the hood, the reason why the dtype is constant inside a column. For numeric columns the type of any data in a column is the same as the dtype of the column and is a numpy numeric datatype. The same occurs with true date or datetime columns.

But as storing strings is a common use case and as many users want to be able to store any Python object, Pandas also offers *object* columns. Here the column dtype is object, and the actual type of the data can be any Python type.

Now for your question:

- if the dtype of the Pandas column is not object, the type of any data in that column will be the same as the column dtype, after an eventual conversion. You will get an exception if the conversion is not possible
- if the dtype of the Pandas column is object, the type of any data in that column will be the original type

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But I think the second point requires some modification: "if the dtype of the Pandas column is object, the type of any data in that column will be the original type". In my code you see an example of <class 'numpy.str_'> which ends up in <class str_'>